# How to document an anonymous function using phpDocumentor?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I usually document my PHP function definitions with a phpDocumentor-style docblock:

```
/**
 * This is a summary of this function.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @return int
 */
function my_return_something() {
    return 20;
}
```

My question is, how should I document an anonymous function? For example:

```
$length = function() {
    return 20;
};
```

Comment: You should document not a function, but a variable instead. It will be `callable` (or, if you need specific reference that it's anonymous function - the `\Closure`)

Comment: I didn't think variables were to be documented with a docblock?

Comment: If used in same context - normally, you don't have to. PHPStorm, for instance, will be perfectly able to get that your `$length` is a closure even without it. For variables documentations, see [the manual](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html). Normally it's not needed.

Comment: @AlmaDo This variable isn't a class property though. It's just a normal variable in global scope.

Comment: @AlmaDo gave you correct answer. If you still want to document argument types/return type for your anonymous functions you are free to document them just like regular functions. This is what PHPStorm does when generates auto docblocks. Everybody will understand that. 

If you add docblocks generate auto documentation then you shouldn't use anonymous functions. They are anonymous and can't be referred by name.

Answer (score 3):

You should not document the anonymous function, instead you should document a variable. It will look like:

```
/** @var \Closure $length */
$length = function() {
    return 20;
};
```

as tag `@var` is applicable for regular variables as well. That, however, normally isn't needed: as PHPDoc is intended to be used by IDE and most of IDE-s will be able to get that your variable is a closure right because you have your assignment.

If you will want to pass that variable somewhere - the you may hint in in the accepting method/function as a `callable` or `\Closure` explicitly, even without PHPDoc (but you also can use PHPDoc as well)

For details about `@var` tag, see the [documentation](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html). Also note, that the closure type or callback will have nothing to do with the value type which is returned by that callback - it is obvious that you're declaring your callback, not calling it (that being said: I assume *"length"* isn't a good name for a callback as it cause confusion. Use some action-related name instead, like *"lengthGetter"* or so)